# Update pod spec without triggering a rollout

Tags: kubernetes

Our current architecture includes several deployments with state, a single replica and a Recreate strategy. Due to this, any rollout of said resources causes downtime. I'm working on rectifying this, but in the meantime, any update to the pod spec of these deployments results in downtime for our app.

Is it possible to update the pod spec of a deployment without triggering a rollout? Specifically, I want to add some tolerations to said Deployments, without a rollout being triggered.

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.3", GitCommit:"721bfa751924da8d1680787490c54b9179b1fed0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-01T20:08:12Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10+", GitVersion:"v1.10.11-gke.1", GitCommit:"5c4fddf874319c9825581cc9ab1d0f0cf51e1dc9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-30T16:18:58Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment)

> A Deployment’s rollout is triggered if and only if the Deployment’s pod template (that is, .spec.template) is changed, for example if the labels or container images of the template are updated. Other updates, such as scaling the Deployment, do not trigger a rollout.

What is the reason behind having a single replica?

Using `Rolling Update Deployment` strategy you can specify `maxSurge` and scale up your deployment during rollout and scale it down once completed.

Comment: Pod tolerations are part of the pod spec, updating them triggers a rollout. I can't duplicate because of Persistent Volumes that can only be mounted on a single pod. Ideally, we'd be able to duplicate these as well with a StatefulSet, but that is a project for another day.

Comment: Whenever you update pod's spec it will pull changes in pod's template and consequently it will trigger rollout update. There's no way to achieve a zero downtime with a single replica and Recreate  strategy